# How to open and output last 15 line from mysql log file via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to open and read mysql error log file from my CentOS server. Is it possible to read and output last 15 lines of this file though PHP? `/var/lib/mysql/{SERVER_NAME}.err`

I have tried following

```
<?php
$file = '/var/lib/mysql/myserver_name.com.err';

$filearray = file($file);
$lastfifteenlines = array_slice($filearray,-15);
var_dump($lastfifteenlines);
?>
```

But this shows

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 854157212 bytes) in /home/myserver_name/public_html/test.php on line 4

Because the error log file size is almost 1GB. So how can I solve this problem? **I need to check this mysql log file in every 5 min**

*My requirement is doing same as `chkservd` does in cPanel*

Comment: [tail-functionality-in-php](http://tekkie.flashbit.net/php/tail-functionality-in-php)

Comment: You can do that directly from server by tail command--"tail -n15 /var/log/myserver.com.err" you can also redirect its output to some other text file...you can also cron it for every 5 minutes...

Comment: @amdixon Thanks it works

Answer (score 0):

use fseek, example:

```
function tail($filename, $n = 10) {
    $file = fopen($filename,'r');
    fseek($file, $n*1024*-1,SEEK_END);
    while ($line = fgets($file)) {
        $lines[] = trim($line);
    }
    return array_slice($lines, -$n);
}
```

Comment: This solution assumes that a line has less than 1024 characters.